# opening a file from a list with os.system

Tags: python-3.x, os.system

I am trying to open a random file from a list I've generated in Python3.

```
import random
BL = ["0.jpg","1.jpg","2.jpg","3.jpg"]
secure_random = random.SystemRandom()
a = secure_random.choice(BL)
os.system('open ./a')
```

I get the error:

```
The file /pathtofile/a does not exist.
256
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: why are you not just using `open`?

Comment: probably because I'm not that smart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change last line into:

```
os.system('open ./{}'.format(a))
```